# ASP.NET DataGrid - Display nested array data

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have a class like so:

```
public class ApplicationInformation
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public List<UserInformation> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I want to display a `List<ApplicationInformation>` in a DataGrid. So I tried this:

```
.aspx:
<asp:DataGrid ID="tbl" runat="server">
</asp:DataGrid>

.aspx.cs:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbl.DataSource = Global.Data;
    tbl.DataBind();
}
```

But that table only has a column titled `ApplicationName`. I want to have a column for each property in `ApplicationInformation` and `UserInformation`, and a separate row for every `UserInformation` in the list in the `List<ApplicationInformation>`.

I hope that made sense...

I looked into templates a bit, but couldn't figure out how to do this. I suppose I could always just loop through everything and create a separate array with all the data I need, but I'd have to make another class, and it just doesn't seem like that's the best way.

***EDIT***

For example, if I have a `List<ApplicationInformation>` like so:

```
{
    { ApplicationInformation
        ApplicationName = "App 1"
        { UserInformation
            UserName = "John Smith"
            ApplicationHost = "JOHN-PC"
        }
        { UserInformation
            UserName = "Mindy from the network"
            ApplicationHost = "MINDY-PC"
        }
    }
    { ApplicationInformation
        ApplicationName = "App 2"
        { UserInformation
            UserName = "John Smith"
            ApplicationHost = "JOHN-PC"
        }
        { UserInformation
            UserName = "Bob Jones"
            ApplicationHost = "BOB-PC"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I want the table to appear like this:

```
  Application Name  |  User Name  |  Application Host
-------------------------------------------------------
  App 1             | John Smith  |  JOHN-PC
  App 1             | Mindy fro...|  MINDY-PC
  App 2             | John Smmith |  JOHN-PC
  App 2             | Bob Jones   |  BOB-PC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either handle ItemDataBound event or use linq to create an anonymous object and bind it to DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

You may construct `anonymous` or `typed` list via Linq:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<ApplicationInformation> app = new List<ApplicationInformation>()
            {
                    new ApplicationInformation()
                    {
                         ApplicationName="App 1",
                         Users=new List<UserInformation>() 
                         {
                             new UserInformation()
                             {
                                  UserName = "John Smith",
                                  ApplicationHost = "JOHN-PC"
                             },
                           new UserInformation()
                             {
                                 UserName = "Mindy from the network",
                                 ApplicationHost = "MINDY-PC"
                             }
                         }
                    },
                    new ApplicationInformation()
                    {
                         ApplicationName="App 2",
                         Users=new List<UserInformation>() 
                         {
                             new UserInformation()
                             {
                                  UserName = "John Smith",
                                  ApplicationHost = "JOHN-PC"
                             },
                           new UserInformation()
                             {
                                 UserName = "Bob",
                                 ApplicationHost = "BOB-PC"
                             }
                         }
                    }
            };

            var result = from ele in app
                          from user in ele.Users 
                         select new
                         {
                              ApplicationName=ele.ApplicationName,
                              UserName=user.UserName ,
                              ApplicationHost=user.ApplicationHost 
                         };

            GridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: But then I wouldn't have another column for every `ApplicationInformation`/`UserInformation` combination...

Comment: My question wasn't very clear; edited the Q with an example :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle RowDataBound as Junaid suggested but you need to have a template column which in itself could be another Datagrid or a List of some sort to Bind `List<UserInformation>` to it.

For example (Untested code):

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

      //find nested grid
      GridView nestedGrid = e.FindControl("NestedGridID") as GridView;
      nestedGrid.DataSource = DataBinder.Eval(e.DataItem,"Users");
      nestedGrid.DataBind();

    }
 }
```

Comment: That would only have one column for every `ApplicationInformation`/`UserInformation` combination though... My description was rather abstract; I'll edit the Q with an example.